# Base Class vs Extended Classes

Tags: selenium-webdriver, instantiation, extends, base-class

I'm a new learner, I'm practicing the base and child classes.  My question is how do we decide which class should be instantiated, extended or the Baseclass?
 Thanks in advance

```
package MavenProject2Package2;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import MavenProject2Package.JavaTesting;

public class JavaTesting2 extends JavaTesting

{

  @Test
     public void f1()
     {      


    JavaTesting a1 = new JavaTesting();  
    System.out.println(a1.msg); 

    JavaTesting2 a2 = new JavaTesting2();  
    System.out.println(a2.msg);         
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base class - it's a class which you should be extending from. - eg - superclass.
In superclass you may put some general fields and methods, which are used across your web app. For example, locators for header as well as footer items, because they are the same for all the pages (mostly).